# Why does CUDAQ (from CUDALink) download data from Wolfram servers?

Tags: cudalink, gpu

I understand why functions like `ElementData` or `CountryData` need to download up-to-date data when first launched. However, when trying to use CUDA for the first time in Mathematica, I ran:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]; CUDAQ[]
```

which downloaded data for several minutes. Given that I have a quite fast net connection, that must amount to a really large amount of data. What does Mathematica download in that case? I guess drivers, but how can I *check* what it downloads?

Comment: Oh, and it took almost 10 minutes to say: `False`. Now I'm pissed off!

Comment: There are a few reasons why it would give False, if you evaluate CUDAInformation[] it might give you some hints and it will forward you to the CUDA setup page (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html)

Comment: mine has just now took 15 minutes and still running...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It installs CUDA Resources, as indicated in the [manual page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html). The resources are platform and driver specific and can also be downloaded manually from [here](http://www.wolfram.com/CUDA/CUDAResources.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links; I had found the first one, not the second. I guess the crux of the question is still unanswered: CUDA functions can download “CUDA resources”, yes, but of what consist said resources?

Comment: the resources consist of the CUDA Toolkit (found on http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-41) plus some extra resources that avoid users hunting for different packages to install. The point of the paclet is to make GPU usage simple, with the only requirement being that the user has appropriate hardware and the nvidia driver. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you think about it, the way they do this is smart. This probably allows wolfram to add support for new hardware without a versioned update. Not sure if they do so of course.